# Using placeholders in sqlite3

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to catch long, lat, and text data from my web application and save it in my database. However, if I use following sql statement I get the error message:

```
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current
statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.

x = request.form['x']
y = request.form['y']
text = request.args['desc']

conn.execute('''INSERT INTO added_marker
(id, adress, geom)
VALUES (NULL, ?, 
GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)', 3857))''' , (text, x, y))
```

I think it has something to do with the `'POINT(? ?)'` query, but can't solve it.

Comment: try with `conn.execute("""INSERT INTO added_marker
(id, adress, geom)
VALUES (NULL, {}, 
GeomFromText('POINT({} {})', 3857))""".format(desc, x, y))`

Comment: now there is following error if I type "my_text" in my input field: `OperationalError: no such column: my_text`

Comment: I think that this error is not generated by my suggestion, but on the other side of the code since not the variable you name has not been used. I recommend testing this piece of code and not your entire project.

Comment: I thought, that the insert into statement creates a row in the existing database, if I try this statementt  `conn.execute('''INSERT INTO added_marker
    (id, adress, geom)
   VALUES (NULL, '%s', 
    GeomFromText('POINT(%s %s)', 3857))''' % (desc, x, y))` no error message occurs, but the database is still empty.

Comment: You tried to execute the query, you may have an error in the construction of the order.